# Sharing ethernet only on Wi-Fi 6E

Tags: networking, wireless

I have an Intel AX210 card Wi-Fi 6E card to share Ethernet over Wi-Fi 6E connection only, using the hotspot function.

I typed nm-connection-editor, clicked Wi-Fi -> Hotspot and there is no choice for 6E band.

I am only allowed to choose between A (5GHz) or B/G (2.4 GHz).

I really need to force it to 6E because the hotspot connection is supposed to be the backbone with another 6E computer.  Thanks.

This is a print out from sudo lshw -class network

```
[sudo] password for auser: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 05
       serial: a8:a1:59:b4:1b:9b
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.5-76051505-generic firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:75200000-7520ffff memory:75210000-75213fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 1a
       serial: 60:dd:8e:11:6b:38
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.5-76051505-generic firmware=66.55c64978.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.uc ip=10.42.0.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:75100000-75103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (17) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 11
       serial: a8:a1:59:b4:1b:9a
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.5-76051505-generic duplex=full firmware=2.3-4 ip=192.168.0.120 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:144 memory:75300000-7531ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: veth4d8616a
       serial: b2:23:03:98:a2:52
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

Answer (score 0):

https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/6-GHz-Wifi-with-AX210-and-Ubuntu-20-04/m-p/1318011

In short, if your location does not allow 6E, the AX210 won't operate in that frequency.